# Do tradespeople get paid as well in other Western countries as they do in Australia?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, income

In Australia, the most highly paid professions right now are electricians and plumbers and tradespeople.
I think this is caused by the mining boom, a housing shortage leading to a laboring skills shortage.

Like it is actually not uncommon for plumbers to be making US$150k a year.

I was wondering, is this similar in other countries like the UK or the US or even New Zealand?

Answer (score 6):

Plumbers are usually in demand.  In the US, they can do very well, especially if they own their own shops.  People like to have dry houses and working toilets.  I've already paid a plumber several hundred dollars for small jobs around my house and my rental that I wasn't confident enough to do myself.

The academically-smart kids (of which I was one) tended to look down on the kids who went into the trade schools while we were in high school.  Some of them are probably doing better than I am financially now!

Electricians, maybe not quite as much, but any skilled trade that has a barrier to entry (education, certification, licensing, etc.) will likely do better than other professions for which there's little or no barrier to entry.

Answer (score 3):

The pay rates for tradesmen took a knock in the UK when the eastern European countries joined the European Union, and lots of Polish tradesmen were able to come to the UK in search of higher wages than in Poland.

Answer (score 2):

If a person puts in the time, joins the trades union (like a Plumber's Local) and goes form apprentice to journeyman to master, then it is quite a good field.

Being a tradespersons isn't free money any more than any other job.  Working hard and putting in time will probably pay off.

There does seem to be a decline in the number of qualified journeymen and apprentices, so that will cause a raise in their prices (aka paychecks)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Salary.com](http://www.salary.com/salary/index.asp), in the USA the averages are:

Plumber I: [$40,444 USD](http://www1.salary.com/Plumber-I-Salary.html)
Plumber II: [$47,692 USD](http://www1.salary.com/Plumber-II-salary.html)
Plumber III: [$51,244 USD](http://www1.salary.com/Plumber-III-salary.html)

Electrician I: [$42,997 USD](http://www1.salary.com/Electrician-I-salary.html)
Electrician II: [$49,650 USD](http://www1.salary.com/Electrician-II-salary.html)
Electrician III: [$52,908 USD](http://www1.salary.com/Electrician-III-salary.html)

Where I, II, and III are entry, intermediate, and senior, respectively.

As a frame of reference, here are the [median earnings by educational attainment in the US for the year 2005:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_income_in_the_United_States#By_educational_attainment)
Some high school:-----------------$20,321
High School:------------------------$26,505
Some College:----------------------$31,056
Associate's degree:----------------$35,009
Bachelor's degree or higher:-----$49,303
Bachelor's degree:-----------------$43,143
Master's degree:--------------------$52,390
Doctorate degree:-----------------$69,432
Professional degree:---------------$82,473

Bear in mind the USA is a large and diverse country, so income and cost of living varies pretty dramatically. Someone making $50,000 in New York City is living very poor, in Alabama, quite rich.